# select tag option not being saved in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I am a new to ruby on rails.I am trying to save the value of the select tag in the database but it's not being saved. Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong. Am I using the select tag in the form correctly

```
<%= link_to("Back" , {:action => 'rpage'}) %>
<%= form_for(:request , :url => {:action => 'servicecreate'}) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :when %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :when %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :where %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :where %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :what %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :what %>
  </div>
  <!--<%= f.select :category,  @categories.each do |article| article end %>-->
  <select name=:category>
    <% @categories.each do |author| %>
        <option value="<%= author %>"><%= author %></option>
    <% end %>
  </select>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :negotiable %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :negotiable %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: use collection_select tag instead.

Comment: can you refer me a link I have tried to understand it but I can't

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the usage as given below which I have implemented in my project.

```
<%= collection_select :user, :user_id, User.all, :id, :first_name,
{:prompt => 'Please Select the User'} %>
```

Further resource can be found at  [Rails FormOptionsHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html)

Comment: James you could replace :user with :category, :user_id with :category_id,  User.all with @categories and :first_name with author. Hope it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have commented out the `f.select` form helper -- replacing it instead with an explicit `<select>` tag. However, Rails expects a specific field naming convention that is enforced by using its form helpers. In this case, the `<select>` tag name should be `request[category]`.

So if you had used

```
  f.select :category, @categories
```

Rails would generate the following HTML (assuming `@categories=['a','bb','ccc']`):

```
<select name="request[category]" id="request_category">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="bb">bb</option>
  <option value="ccc">ccc</option>
</select>
```

Another problem might be that the `category` field is not white-listed in the controller. E.g. you should have something like

```
 params.require(:request).permit(:when, :where, :what, :category, :negotiable, :price)
```

Check Rails log files (printed on screen in development mode) for a "category not permitted" message.